# winston-daily-rotate-file prepend option not working

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have my winston setup as follows

```
// Config import.
var config = require('../config');

// Library imports.
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.Console)({
            level: 'debug',
            colorize: true,
            timestamp: true,
            json: true,
            showLevel: true
        }),
        new(require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
            prepend: true,
            level: 'debug',
            colorize: true,
            timestamp: true,
            filename: 'log.txt',
            maxSize: config.log.maxSize,
            json: true,
            prettyPrint: true 
        })
    ]
});
```

It logs to the console fine - as expected.
It logs to file fine - as expected.

However, the filename has the date tacked onto the end of the filename, not the beginning, like the `prepend` option would suggest.

Is anyone able to offer any insight into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this one out - I'm a bit silly.

The version showing in `master` on the project's github page is not the same as the version that is dished out by `npm install` - the version that is served via npm doesn't currently have support for the prepend option.

Hopefully a release is coming soon :)